# Notice: Undefined index: enroll in G:\xampp\htdocs\tg\1stSubmit.php on line 10

Tags: php, mysql

when i insert data in mysql, this error are generated.

> Notice: Undefined index: enroll in G:\xampp\htdocs\tg\1stSubmit.php on line 10

`enroll` is a defined in  `<input type="text" name="enroll">` and on submit page declare :

```
$a =  $POST['enroll'];
$sql="INSERT INTO student (e_no,f_name) VALUES ('$a','$b')";
```

Comment: *sidenote:* your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow POST values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: e_no is integer or varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$a = $_POST['enroll'];
```

instead of

```
$a = $POST['enroll'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a typo,

```
$a =  $_POST['enroll']; //you missed "_" should be _POST
```

And always check if post variable really exists or not,

```
$a =  isset($_POST['enroll']) ? $_POST['enroll'] : "";
```

[*Reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index).

**Warning:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).